# nodejs app works fine locally but not online

Tags: node.js, web, socket.io

I have created a card game using nodejs and socket.io (first application).
Locally, it works perfectly.
I tried to host it on alwaysdata but it doesn't work like it should work.

In local : A username is asked to the user when he go on the site. Usernames are displayed. When two players are on the site and have entered username, the game start.

On alwaysdata : Things go well until the second player enter his username. When he enter his username, this username is displayed for the first player, but not for himself. His username is asked again (not supposed to happen). In the console there is an error : 
GET http://scopa.alwaysdata.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N6HwT42 502 (Bad Gateway)

This is my code for the server :

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express();
const path = require('path');

const directory = path.join(__dirname, '.');
const Jeu = require(__dirname + '/js/Jeu.js');
const Joueur = require(__dirname + '/js/Joueur.js');


app.use(express.static(directory));
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

function gestionsocket(){
    let joueurs = [];
    let nbConnexion = 0;
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        ++nbConnexion;
        if(nbConnexion > 2){
            --nbConnexion;
            socket.disconnect();
            return;
        }

        //display username of the first player if it's the second player who is connected
        if(joueurs.length == 1) socket.emit("affiche pseudo", joueurs[0].pseudo);

        //ask username
        socket.emit('demande pseudo', joueurs.length + 1);

        //when username is send by the client
        socket.on('envoie pseudo', function(pseudo){
            //display username of the second player for everyone
            //things go wrong here
            io.emit("affiche pseudo", pseudo);

            joueurs.push(new Joueur(socket, pseudo));
            if(joueurs.length == 2) {
                let lesJoueurs = joueurs;
                Jeu.commencer(lesJoueurs, io);
                joueurs = [];
            }
        });



        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            nbConnexion--;
            io.emit("deconnexion");
            joueurs = [];
        });
    });



    http.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
        console.log('listening');
    });
}


gestionsocket();
```

I don't understand why it's working localy and not online and don't know what to do.
I'm really sorry for my english.

Comment: seems to work now, though infinite refresh if more then 2 connected which is due to `if(nbConnexion > 2){` you may have got Bad Gateway when the app crashed/restart after changing something

Comment: still not working.. How can I do to avoid the problem with this condition ? avoid the restart ?

Comment: it might be your host https://www.google.com/search?q=Connection+to+upstream+skipped+site:forum.alwaysdata.com

Comment: What's the tech. stack that's involved between the server and the client